# Cant figure out whats wrong with my syntax - python Codevue practice - very basic beginner level

Tags: python, syntax

I'm not sure where I am going wrong with my code here are the instructions from codevue. It automatically starts with with the top portion up to print(line), then I fill the rest of the code out myself.

Input:
Each test case will pass this value to your code through stdin ("Standard In")

Output:
Each test case's Output value will be compared to what your code writes to stdout ("Standard Out").

If your program's output matches the Expected Output, the test case will pass and be shown in green in the output panel.

If your program's output does NOT math the Expected Output for a test case, the result will be displayed in red in the output panel.

- **Test 1**
  **Test Input**
  "Test Case 3"
  **Expected Output**
  "Try writing code to pass all 3 tests"
- **Test 2**
  **Test Input**
  "This is Test case 2"
  **Expected Output**
  "This is the expected Output. Try changing the code to write this to STDOUT for this case."
- **Test 3**
  **Test Input**
  "This is the input for Test 1"
  **Expected Output**
  "This is the input for Test 1"

**My syntax below here starting after print(line) call.**

`

```
import sys

# This entire script will be run once for each Test Input.
# The Input for each test will be passed through the filelike object
# `sys.stdin` (STDIN).

# This provides a single line from the Test Input for each iteration.
for line in sys.stdin:
    # You'll want to write some code to pass all of the tests.
    # if "2" in line:
    #   print("This is the expected Output. Try changing the code to write this to STDOUT for this case.")

    # This writes `line` to STDOUT.
    print(line)
    x = input()

    if(x == "Test Case 3"):
        print("Try writing code to pass all 3 tests")
    elif(x == "This is Test case 2"):
        print("This is the expected Output. Try changing the code to write this to STDOUT for this case.")
    else:
        print("This is the input for Test 1")
```

`

if else branches to execute one print function for three different input values.

Comment: why are you doing `x=input()`? shouldn't you be comparing `line` instead of `x`?  It's unclear what your inputs are, since you read `line` from `sys.stdin` but you also read `x` using `input`

Comment: Alright, sorry for the noob question. I am starting to learn coding as of this year. I changed all of the syntax from 'x' to 'line' and I am still getting an error on line 16.

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/source.py", line 16, in <module>
    line = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line```

Comment: The output I get every time is simply the input put in. It seems none of the if else branches are firing.

Comment: What makes you think there's a syntax error? Are you getting an error message? Pleaes [edit] your question and paste in the exact, complete error message.

Comment: remove the input line at all. line is already iterating what you put in the stdin

Comment: thanks! After looking at it with what you said, I understood it a lot more. It worked. I also didn't realize the for loop it set up for me... Sorry!